# Eclipse SSH auth failure

Tags: eclipse, ssh, egit

When trying to push my project to an existing remote repository with EGit, I get a SSH authentication failure. Eclipse can find my key and I can push the same project with Git Bash, but EGit still fails to authenticate. Same happens when trying to add the remote.

Comment: Do you have Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14) with EGit 5.6? If not, please upgrade. If yes, try switching the SSH client in _Windwo > Preferences: Team > Git_. If this does not help, please show what is in the error log.

Comment: Okay so I was using the version of Eclipse that comes with Scala IDE - Oxygen (4.7), released in 2017... Anyways, after updating Eclipse git worked immediately, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a very old version of Eclipse due to downloading it with the Scala IDE and not checking that Oxygen was released in 2017. After updating to the newest version everything works. The Scala IDE plugin works well too.

Edit: Actually nevermind that, I can't add breakpoints (they aren't being skipped, rather they don't show up at all) and there are some issues with the coloring.

Either way, the original problem has been solved